# Flask not compiling SCSS

Tags: python, flask, sass

I'm trying to setup SCSS to run with my Flask app, but to no success. 
I have a simple folder structure like so:

```
app/
    static/
        css/
        scss/
            main.scss
    templates/
__init__.py
views.py
```

and the contents of my `__init___.py` are:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.assets import Environment, Bundle
from flaskext.sass import sass

app = Flask(__name__)

assets = Environment(app)
assets.url = app.static_url_path
scss = Bundle('scss/main.scss', filters='pyscss', output='css/all.css')
assets.register('scss_all', scss)

from app import views
```

And from what I'm told the `main.scss` file should be compiled and put into the `css` directory but it doesn't. I have tried many different Flask/Scss compilers but none seem to do the trick.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: How do you run the app?

Comment: A python file in the parent directory with this code:
`import os`
`#!flask/bin/python`
`from app import app`


`app.run(debug=True, host=os.getenv('IP', `'0.0.0.0'),port=int(os.getenv('PORT', 8080)))`